# Can't make a function call in in spite of the using-statement and extension needed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

So I wanted to be able to choose my environment when running `dotnet` (an .net core mvc-project) from the terminal. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322565/dotnet-run-or-dotnet-watch-with-development-environment-from-command-line) and thought the second highest answer was a neat way of solving it, in short:

Replacing the Program class body with the following:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> defaults =
new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { WebHostDefaults.EnvironmentKey, "development" }
};

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var configuration =
        new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(defaults)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables("ASPNETCORE_")
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Then running:

```
dotnet run environment=development
dotnet run environment=staging
```

So I pasted it, and it said I need to add a using statment

`using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;`

Still got this error message:

```
'IConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
'AddCommandLine' and no extension method 'AddCommandLine' 
accepting a first argument of type 'IConfigurationBuilder' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)
```

I'm a bit at loss for what could be the problem. I mean, [here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.commandlineconfigurationextensions) the definition of `AddCommandLine(IConfigurationBuilder, String[])`
 with namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`?

Comment: Which version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` are you using?

Comment: Hmm, first there were red squigglies under `ConfigurationBuilder`, then it just suggested I added `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` which I did. Didn't think of it, but now that you asked I took a look at my `.deps.json`-file and under `"microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting/1.1.2": { "dependencies": {` there's a line saying `"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.1.2",`. So I suppose it's version 1.1.2?

Comment: Yes, that's the version number.

Comment: Ah, I think I've got it - do you have a dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine`? That's where the extension method comes from.

Comment: Yes! I ran `dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine` and then all the issues went away. unfortunately it seems it makes little difference whether I run `dotnet run environment=development` or `dotnet run environment=production` or simply `dotnet run`. It seems to be in production mode regardless, though it runs in development when I run it through f5 (as per the instructions of the `launch.json`). So I suppose I learned a way to test both modes, albeit far less elegant. Though I guess that's another question and you've certainly helped me with this one. Thank you!

Comment: Just add the answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure whether we want to encourage questions which are basically "I haven't checked the dependencies". I'll add it this one time, but please check for dependencies yourself next time.

Comment: Ah, ok. Didn't think about that. At least I learned to not only look at the namespace but at the assembly as well, which was new info for me. Thanks!

Comment: I actually listed [this package as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322565/dotnet-run-or-dotnet-watch-with-development-environment-from-command-line/39131944?noredirect=1#comment65690597_39131944) to my answer. Vote it up so it is less likely that others miss this in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the *namespace* is `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, the extension is in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine` assembly, which is in the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine/). You need to add a dependency on that package.