# Automatically set appsettings.json for dev and release environments in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I've defined some values in my `appsettings.json` for things like database connection strings, webapi locations and the like which are different for development, staging and live environments.

Is there a way to have multiple `appsettings.json` files (like `appsettings.live.json`, etc, etc) and have the asp.net app just 'know' which one to use based on the build configuration it's running?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You may use conditional compilation:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
#if SOME_BUILD_FLAG_A
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.flag_a.json", optional: true)
#else
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.no_flag_a.json", optional: true)
#endif
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    this.configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: You should set your environment variable in your MSBuild/TFS build. Conditional compilation leads to mistakes for something easily handled in CI builds. I.e., .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)

Comment: See my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50331886/1319086) for Environment variable

Comment: This kind of approach forces the code to be recompiled specifically for each environment, making it impossible to be redistributed/installed elsewhere.

Comment: Question was about “knowing about build configuration”

Comment: This should not be marked as the accepted answer - though it is a solution it's not best practice.

Comment: @Charleh that's answer to question. But I'm agree that readers should know that such question means that they possibly misunderstand some aspnetcore basics. Please feel free to suggest edit to add some warning and best practice link(s).

Comment: Not correct answer.The question is: how to set automatically for configuration. This answer has hard-code...

Comment: @AlexSham This is probably the best answer you could give, given that Microsoft seem to have shifted a lot of the build stuff to code, rather than xml files. Alas, you can't just automatically toggle Configuration/Environmental variables as they are usually Environmental variables of the OS.

Answer (score 235):

### Update for .NET Core 3.0+

1. You can use [`CreateDefaultBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder) which will automatically build and pass a configuration object to your startup class:

   ```cs
   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
   ```

   ```cs
   public class Startup
   {
       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) // automatically injected
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }
       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
       /* ... */
   }
   ```
2. `CreateDefaultBuilder` automatically includes the appropriate `appsettings.Environment.json` file so add a separate appsettings file for each environment:

   [image: appsettings.env.json]
3. Then set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` **environment variable** when running / debugging

### How to set Environment Variables

Depending on your IDE, there are a couple places dotnet projects traditionally look for environment variables:

- For **Visual Studio** go to Project > Properties > Debug > Environment Variables:

  [image: Visual Studio - Environment Variables]
- For **Visual Studio Code**, edit `.vscode/launch.json` > `env`:

  [image: Visual Studio Code > Launch Environment]
- Using **Launch Settings**, edit `Properties/launchSettings.json` > `environmentVariables`:

  [image: Launch Settings]

  Which can also be selected from the Toolbar in Visual Studio

  [image: Launch Settings Dropdown]
- Using **dotnet CLI**, use the appropriate syntax for [setting environment variables per your OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43992754/1366033)

  > **Note**: When an app is launched with [dotnet run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run),  `launchSettings.json` is read if available, and `environmentVariables` settings in launchSettings.json override environment variables.

#### How does `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` work?

.NET Core 3.0 added [`Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder) under platform extensions which will provide a default initialization of [`IConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration) which provides default configuration for the app in the following order:

> 1. `appsettings.json` using the [JSON configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#file-configuration-provider).
> 2. `appsettings.Environment.json` using the [JSON configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#file-configuration-provider).  For example:
>
>    - `appsettings.Production.json` or
>    - `appsettings.Development.json`
> 3. [App secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets) when the app runs in the Development environment.
> 4. Environment variables using the [Environment Variables configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#evcp).
> 5. Command-line arguments using the [Command-line configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#command-line).

#### Further Reading - MS Docs

- [App startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup)
- [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)
- [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

Comment: Thanks, it is good but How to do that with the console process (or worker process template/scaffolding)?

Comment: This does not work with latest version, it will always take appsettings.json and ignore appsettings.development.json. Run (dev) and run (prod) is also missing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Would this work for custom environment names as well? For example, if I wanted to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT as "Dev". Will an appsettings called appsettings.Dev.json be automatically picked up?

Comment: @Mehnaz, I believe so.  I don't think you're bound by any preset available environment names.  It'll just take whatever name you set in your environment variable and use that to build the naming rules for the app settings file.

Comment: Does "Host" mean web hosting? I mean, I had been thinking so, but today, I created a .NET 7.0 console project, and to use DI, I had to add Hosting, and then to adjust logging, I had to add appsettings.[Development].json. But why does it need "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"? Is it just a relic of the past, or is Hosting/appsettings for ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I would add that if using VS2022, it is accessed via Debug > (ProjectName) Debug Properties.

Answer (score 156):

I have added screenshots of a working environment, because it cost me several hours of R&D.

1. First, add a key to your `launch.json` file.

   See the below screenshot, I have added **`Development`** as my environment.

   [image: Declaration of the environment variable in launch.json]
2. Then, in your project, create a new `appsettings.{environment}.json` file that includes the name of the environment.

   In the following screenshot, look for two different files with the names:

   - `appsettings.Development.Json`
   - `appSetting.json`

   [image: Project view of appsettings JSON files]
3. And finally, configure it to your `StartUp` class like this:

   ```cs
   public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables();

       Configuration = builder.Build();
   }
   ```
4. And at last, you can run it from the command line like this:

   ```sh
   dotnet run --environment "Development"
   ```

   where **`"Development"`** is the name of my environment.

Comment: Tried this and it works great. VS2017 even displays the different versions as under the base file. up vote.

Comment: how do you do it in core 2.2 as ihostingenvironment is deprected

Comment: @djack109 you should use `IWebHostEnvironment` instead.

Answer (score 64):

In ASP.NET Core you should rather use Environment Variables instead of build configuration for proper appsettings.json

1. Right click on you project > Properties > Debug > Environment Variables

   [image: environment variables]
2. ASP.NET Core will use the appropriate appsettings.json file:

   [image: example of appsettings files in solution explorer]
3. Now you can use that Environment Variable like this:

   ```cs
   public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables();

       Configuration = builder.Build();
   }
   ```

> **Note**: If you use [@Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c/46364874#46364874), you can run into problems eg. when **overriding appsettings.json values on Azure.**

Answer (score 43):

You can make use of environment variables and the `ConfigurationBuilder` class in your `Startup` constructor like this:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    this.configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Then you create an `appsettings.xxx.json` file for every environment you need, with "xxx" being the environment name. Note that you can put all global configuration values in your "normal" `appsettings.json` file and only put the environment specific stuff into these new files.

Now you only need an environment variable called `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with some specific environment value ("live", "staging", "production", whatever). You can specify this variable in your project settings for your development environment, and of course you need to set it in your staging and production environments also. The way you do it there depends on what kind of environment this is.

**UPDATE:** I just realized you want to choose the `appsettings.xxx.json` based on your current *build configuration*. This cannot be achieved with my proposed solution and I don't know if there is a way to do this. The "environment variable" way, however, works and might as well be a good alternative to your approach.

Comment: I looked at using environment variables, in the project properties->debug section, however there's no obvious way how this will change based on project settings. Is that another file I can add to my project to handle it?

Comment: Setting the variable within the project properties will only work for using it in your development environment (probably Visual Studio). You will need to set it elsewhere for your deployed apps depending on the specific environment (IIS, Azure). I would not recommend to set the variable in some configuration file because this file might get deployed, too, and then override the server values.

Comment: You set it up in build configurations. If there is not a build configuration file then they are doing it manually, so they would need to set it up in the (archaic) deployment profile

Comment: I have multiple environments like test, staging and production in Azure. Where do I change ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable if I want to publish the release build of web app from VS to Azure?

Comment: We don't change the variables during deployment, instead, they are built in to the specific environment. In Azure, you can set these values directly within your app service configuration unter "Application settings". Don't forget to mark them as "Deployment slot settings" in case you're working with multiple slots.

Comment: In latest version environment variables are ignored!

Answer (score 33):

Just an update for .NET core 2.0 users, you can specify application configuration after the call to `CreateDefaultBuilder`:

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      BuildWebHost(args).Run();
   }

   public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureAppConfiguration(ConfigConfiguration)
             .UseStartup<Startup>()
             .Build();

   static void ConfigConfiguration(WebHostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder config)
   {
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"config.{ctx.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

   }
 }
```

Comment: How do you switch between the environments being used? Are there changes supposed to be made in any config file? I understand I'll need to add the URL I want to be using when the project runs on Azure to *appsettings.json* and the URL I want to execute when run locally (by F5) to *appsettings.Development.json*. Is that correct? My string that I want to be using is in the file *launchSettings.json* and I'm a bit unclear on how to alter it based on where the application is executed (or if it's supposed to be altered at all).

Comment: @DonkeyBanana The environment is nothing more than a setting specified in project properties. In VS 2017, right click on the project > properties. Under debug, you will see the current environment for key `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`. The value is what will be replaced  for `ctx.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}`. So if you set that value in properties to 'Production', the project will look for `config.Production.json` file in the root folder. For more info, please view this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1#setting-the-environment)

Comment: Creates an `Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` in WebHost.CreateDefaultBuiler(...

Comment: It's worth noting that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#json-configuration-provider) it states  "AddJsonFile is automatically called twice when you initialize a new host builder with CreateDefaultBuilder". In other words, it is already loading appSettings.json and then based on your environment configuration, it is loading appsettings.{Environment}.json

Comment: @umutsen In latest visual  studio there is no more run environment settings

Answer (score 24):

1. Create multiple `appSettings.$(Configuration).json` files like:

   - `appSettings.staging.json`
   - `appSettings.production.json`
2. Create a pre-build event on the project which copies the respective file to `appSettings.json`:

   ```sh
   copy appSettings.$(Configuration).json appSettings.json
   ```
3. Use only `appSettings.json` in your Config Builder:

   ```cs
   var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();

   Configuration = builder.Build();
   ```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. For complicated cases [SlowCheetah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53235364/2746150) may be used.

Comment: How do you create a pre-build event on the project? Where should that line starting copy... actually be put?

Comment: @Paul In Visual Studio, right-click on the Project in the Solution Explorer view, select `Properties` from the right-click menu, then select `Build Events` in the properties view.

Comment: This is perfect - allows me to build the app and deploy our QA/Test and UAT onto the one machine without having to copy the app settings and using the above methods of setting it at machine level.

Exactly what was needed - and I think what the person was looking for above.

Comment: Where do you get the `AddEnvironmentVariables` extension from?

Comment: This does not work with .NET 6/7 (perhaps not even with earlier version). What this does is allowing you to read current environment variables through `Configuration` instance (e.g. `var environmetnName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")`)

Answer (score 24):

This is version that works for me when using a console app without a web page:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true);

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
            AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
            configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(appSettings);
```

Comment: You may need to add Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions to your .net 6 project.

Answer (score 9):

You can add the configuration name as the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in the `launchSettings.json` as below

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58446/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "environmentVariables": {
        ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "$(Configuration)"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

By adding the environment name in between the `"appsettings"` and `".json"` part of the filename, it will override any settings that are in the main `appsettings.json` file.

For example, in the likehood that you have a different SQL Server connection string for a production environment, you can add that connection string to `appsettings.Production.json`, and it will use the value from that file.

[image]

To choose the profile or environment, open `launchSettings.json` and set the environment in **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT**:

```
   "IIS Express": {
     "commandName": "IISExpress",
     "launchBrowser": true,
     "environmentVariables": {
       "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
     }
   }
```

and setup:

```
var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", true, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Answer (score 5):

.vscode/launch.json file is only used by Visual Studio as well as /Properties/launchSettings.json file. Don't use these files in production.

The launchSettings.json file:

1. Is only used on the local development machine.
2. Is not deployed.
3. contains profile settings.

   - Environment values set in launchSettings.json override values set in the system environment

To use a file 'appSettings.QA.json' for example. You can use 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT'. Follow the steps below.

1. Add a new Environment Variable on the host machine and call it 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT'. Set its value to 'QA'.
2. Create a file 'appSettings.QA.json' in your project. Add your configuration here.
3. Deploy to the machine in step 1. Confirm 'appSettings.QA.json' is deployed.
4. Load your website. Expect appSettings.QA.json to be used in here.

Comment: Does it meant, that if you have 5 environments and 5 appsettings.EnvName.json files, all of them will be deployed and just one selected machine because artifacts of the build definition will contain all 5 files ? Or only appsettings.json (as main) + appsettings.CurrentEnvironment.json (as overrides)  should be deployed and how?

Answer (score 2):

### For .NET 6.0+

Example `launchSettings.json` is as following

```
...
"profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5081",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
...
```

We can obtain `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` section as following

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");`

How I use as following, in which I am using PostgreSql.

```
public RepositoryContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
    var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json")
        .Build();

    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RepositoryContext>()
        .UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection"));

    return new RepositoryContext(builder.Options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that I wanted to change the appsettings.*.json file based on my chosen configuration in VS and I just discovered that you can just put "$(Configuration)" as value for "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" in your launchSettings.json.

This lets the default HostBuilder automatically pick the right appsettings.*.json-file.

I assume you still should do some other things so that your dev.appsettings won't be copied to production-server like described here for example [Environment Based appsettings.json Configuration for publishing in .NET 5](https://dev.to/caiocesar/environment-based-appsettings-json-configuration-for-publishing-in-net-5-3pb). But it does the trick to test different environment during development and inside VS w/o deploying to another server or to manually set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT-variable.

BTW: I tested with VS. I am not sure whether this also works with VS-Code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep appsettings.json similar to appsettings.Development.json
It works automatically

Example appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=myserver;Database=mydb;User=myuser;Password=mypassword;"
  }
}
```

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=myserver;Database=mydb;User=myuser;Password=mypassword;"
      }
    }
```