# Visual Studio 2017 Always Deploying in Development Mode

Tags: asp.net-core, publishing, microsoft-web-deploy

I have an ASP.NET Core application that I'm attempting to perform web deploy to a server and no matter what build configuration I select in the profile wizard, it always deploys multiple appsettings files as well as the PDB files for the DLLs.  Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: I haven't tried this just yet, but I found this question and it seems like it's what I'm looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c

Comment: Now I've discovered that part of the configuration is the launchSettings.json file that I've never seen.  Now I'm researching that to see if I can configure each environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude `.pdb` files for release publishing, then you may disable their generation during release build by adding next property to `.csproj` file (found this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2246))

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DebugType Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">None</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

Regarding any configuration (or not) file, it will be published based on `CopyToPublishDirectory` attribute value. So again, you may use `Condition` attribute and have something like this (just an idea):

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
   <Content Update="appsettings.debug.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always"/>
   <Content Update="appsettings.release.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never"/>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
   <Content Update="appsettings.debug.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never"/>
   <Content Update="appsettings.release.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

But in general, it's better to depend on environment setting (Dev, Prod) when we are talking about configs.