# how to set the environment of dotnet core in docker?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I want to be able to run dotnet core by docker in different environments(for now just development and production) but my docker always start in production environment.
here is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env

WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test.dll"]
```

I have appsettings.Production.json and appsettings.Development.json
and I have configured my two environments in program.cs like below:

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder (string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder (args)

            .ConfigureAppConfiguration ((hostingContext, config) => {
                config.AddJsonFile ("appsettings.Development.json", optional : false, reloadOnChange : false)
                    .AddJsonFile ("appsettings.Production.json", optional : false, reloadOnChange : false);
            })
            //End of update
            .UseStartup<Startup> ();
```

I build the docker image and container but when it starts it starts in production mode I want it to start in development mode

Answer (score 16):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test.dll", "--environment=Development"]
```

Comment: That helped me!

Answer (score 12):

ASP.NET Core reads the following environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` if not set then it defaults to `production`. What you need to do is to use this in your Dockerfile

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development
```

Or if you are using docker-compose.yml file

```
environment:
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
```

For more details:

- [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [ENV usage in Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)

Comment: I did that but still when I am running docker log it says this: Hosting environment: Production

Comment: maybe you need to modify your code in order to make it detect the actual environment as shown in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environments

Comment: also what if you changed the name of the config file in your code to `appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json`

Comment: then how to set different connection strings for different environments?
here is my appsetings.json now:
{ "ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "test"
},
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}

Comment: and for the code modification part, I have done that in my launchsettins.json before and it works by itself but in docker it does not

Comment: have you checked the following question ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46364293/2336650

Comment: yes. I can run my code from terminal like dotnet run --environment "Development" or production. the problem is with docker

Comment: I am not an expert in dotnet but what about using this `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run","--environment","Development","test.dll"]`

Comment: Also note that i have updated the answer to make Development with capital letter

Comment: Great answer, helped a lot. If using a console app and docker-compose you may require DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. My Project has 3 appsetings.json inside (one generic and two for development and production like this appsettings.development.json and appsettings.producation.json).
I tried these:

1. Not to mention environment in any docker files as I don't wanna stick to file (and source control respectively) because I should have possibility to run same image in different environments. I starts my container with --env ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=development or DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=development with no result.
2. I added ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT development to my dockerfile and it works. But this make me lose procs from 1st note. So I removed it.
3. I start my container just with --env Environment=development and it somehow works! Miracle! Actually I still don't know why it works. Is 'Environment' a docker's built-in variable? And how it relate to ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT? Or is ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT (and DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT) variable dig to ENVIRONMENT variable eventually?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify the environ while running the container, it will take “Production” by default.

To run another environ:

`docker run -d -p 8000:80 –name something –env ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development myimage`

Comment: I ran it but it gives this error \Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format.

Comment: There needs to be two dashes in front of --env flag. Otherwise use just -e

Comment: --env didn't work at all for me, but -e worked like a charm