# AppSettings connection strings must be configurable by environment (Dev, Staging, UAT and Production)

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I develop the code for my application against the Sandbox environment in Azure. my current appsettings.json file contains connection strings for Database, Azure Storage, etc which point to the Sandbox environment.

When the api is deployed through the DevOps pipeline to Dev, Staging and Production Env, the api should point to Database, azure Storage etc that are present in the respective environments Dev, staging and production.

I am trying to go with approach in Startup file

But I can't able to go further on the above to achieve this is in DevOps deployment.

Comment: public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    if (env.IsProduction() || env.IsStaging() || env.IsEnvironment("Staging_2"))
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
}

Comment: I got answer for the above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by **JSON variable substitution**. For more information, refer [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#json-variable-substitution)