# Visual Studio Net Core: Switch Environment Variables for Multiple Projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, powershell, .net-core

We have multiple Projects in a Solution, and need a way to quickly change Environment to Another One, say QA. There are 8 projects in our solution. How can this be done, without manually going through each ?

Is there quick setting in Visual Studio?

[image]

Note: We have a multiple number of API projects, which have non dependencies.

Comment: You should checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c

Comment: hi @DanielLeach we have that setup in Azure devops, but testing locally for right now

Comment: This link might be helful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c/50331886#50331886

Comment: Do you mean U need a way to quickly change environment from VS say from Dev to QA or Staging?

Comment: And have you tried using different configurations for different environments?

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what need you want to fulfill by doing this. Care to clarify on your actual need? There might be another solution to fulfill your need other than doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown on your screenshot, the "app environment" is determined by that "windows process environment variable". Only the project that is being run needs to set that environment variable, not the projects refenced by that one.

If you are running multiple projects at the same time:
The environment variable is saved to the launchSettings.json file in the project folder. You could us a PowerShell script to update the launchSettings of many projects at once.

Comment: Note: We have a multiple number of API projects, which have non dependencies.  and all 5 api projects are running

Comment: is there a native way, in VS without using powershell? thanks

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: do you have a sample powershell script by any chance? I can use as example template

Comment: this is a great answer, probably most straightforward, if someone is a powershell expert, feel free to add on

Comment: You don't specifically have to use PowerShell. You could make a C# console app that edits the launchSettings.json files using the Newtonsoft.Json library. Whatever you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is to have a solution-level "environment" text file, that each API project can "link" to. Then in each API project's `Program` or `Startup` logic, have them read this global file to set the environment at run time.

As an example, here's my sample solution which has 2 API projects in it:

[image]

### Step 1: Create The 'Global' Environment File

Firstly, I added a solution-level text file `Environment.txt` that simply has the name of the 'current' environment I wish to run all my API's under:

```
Performance
```

### Step 2: Link The Environment.txt File To Each API Project

Second is **linking** the `Environment.txt` file to each API project, using Visual Studio's `Add Existing Item` dialog, and choosing the `Add As Link` option:

[image]

Notice that the icon on linked files is slightly different than a normal file.

### Step 3: Ensure Environment.txt Actually Gets Copied To The Bin Directory(s)

Thirdly is ensuring that each of the added linked file's `Copy to Output` option is set to `Copy Always`:

[image]

### Step 4: A Small Bit Of Code...

And finally, in each API project's `Program.cs` file, you can read this file and set the environment at run-time:

```
namespace MicroserviceSandbox.ApiTwo
{
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    // *** Dynamically set the environment.
                    var binDirectoryPath = new FileInfo(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location).Directory.FullName;
                    var environmentFilePath = Path.Combine(binDirectoryPath, "Environment.txt");
                    var environment = File.ReadAllText(environmentFilePath);
                    webBuilder.UseEnvironment(environment);
                    // ***

                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

### Assumptions

- The above C# code snippet assumes your API projects are using ASP.NET Core v3.1.

Comment: Yes, that'll ensure each project is using the same environment. But it doesn't solve the 2nd part of the question: What if you have DEV, QA, UAT, ... environments? How can you switch these easily? I know, similar to "Debug" and "Release" you can create multiple configurations in VS, but how to reference these with the C# code snippet?

Comment: @Matt - Are you referring to environmental specific appsettings.json files? I believe that's already taken care of as long as they follow the standard naming convention appsettings.[environment].json where environment can be the same as you specify in the solution level environment file. And any shared setting can be in the appsetting.json file (non environment specific one).

Comment: this is a great answer, I upvoted, but asks us to make too many changes to current project setup which exists

Comment: @ajawad987 - Yes, indeed, in the .json file there can be an environment section so you don't need to do that separately. I have updated that in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63504548/1016343).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the environment variables from the project launchsettings, you can also use the system environment variables.

To do so, you have to remove the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" from the launchsettings and set in system enviroment variables.
See docu here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-the-environment

Caution: Every project on the same machinge not having the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" set in the launchsetting will use the system enviroment variable

Answer (score 1):

There a couple of things described in the articles below:

1. [Automatically set appsettings.json for dev and release environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c)
2. [launchSettings.json in ASP.NET](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/launchsetting-json-in-aspnet-5/)
3. [Various configuration json files in ASP.NET](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/various-configuration-json-files-in-asp-net-5/)

The first one is a step by step instruction how to set up **appsettings.json** for multiple environments; in the 2nd article you find important information about **launchSettings.json** and how different sets of environment variables can be configured. Here you'll find an example how you can set up environment variables for 3 different configurations like "Development", "Staging" and "Production".

Also there are startup conventions in Startup.cs like "StartupDevelopment" or "StartupProduction" being called if you switched the deployment platform.

Essentially, to set this up, you'll need a combination of these to set up your environment variables properly. I'd use [ajawad987's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63479567/1016343) but change the environment file path to `var environmentFilePath = Path.Combine(binDirectoryPath,$"Environment.{env.EnvironmentName}.txt");`, allowing to set it depending to the environment (the variable comes from `Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)` - you might need to add a global property accessible from his code). His code should be added to all projects. Note that you can either set up `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` as system environment variable or run it via commandline like `dotnet run --environment "Development"`.

But note you can also declare environment variables in the `launchSetting.json` file, e.g.

```
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
  }
},
```

This JSON file holds project specific settings associated with each profile Visual Studio is configured to use to launch the application.

What is also worthwhile to look into is the 3rd article about [Various configuration json files in ASP.NET](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/various-configuration-json-files-in-asp-net-5/), there you can find a description of all json files that exist in current ASP.NET Core projects, and what role they are playing in your project.

It is a pitty that the inventors of .NET core didn't implement that more straightforward!

Comment: these are great resources, however, I need to change it for Multiple Projects in one click, rather than many environments, wish I had more direct answer

Comment: I tried to be more direct on this, hope it is clearer now.