# Where is HostEnvrionment setup in Startup.cs?

Tags: web, .net-core

I have a .Net core console application and when I run it the following method is hit in Startup.cs class

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

If I check the contents of env, the **EnvironmentName** property is set to Production. I am wondering, where in the code path does it identify whether the environment is DEV, QA or Production?

Comment: Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c). This could be coming from the project properties or the appsettings.json file (if it exists).

Comment: @insane_developer  - Actually, thats what I want to know. I have 4 appsettings.json files one for each environment. How does the application choose which one to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not showing the relevant configuration code to work with multiple appsetting.json files, all I can do is [point you to a resource](https://keestalkstech.com/2019/01/setup-multiple-setting-files-with-a-net-console-application/) that shows how to properly do it in a Console application. This is how I normally see it done in web applications.