# How to set appsettings.json automatically for deployment in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I look at several topics e.g. [Automatically set appsettings.json for dev and release environments in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c) and see that I can create appsettings.{Environment}.json in .NET Core apps and set the environment in `launchSettings.json`.

However, I am wondering what should I do to set this environment properly while publishing my app to IIS or Docker container. Before each publishing, should I change the `environmentVariables` parameter to Prod and then update it to Development after publish? I do not think so, but I could not find a suitable page explaining this. Could you please clarify me about this issue?

Comment: You need to set the environment variable on the respective machine and asp.net will read from the respective json based on environment variable

Comment: `launchSettings.json` is [only used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) on the local development machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you. Then as far as I understood, in the development machine, I can easily switch between PROD and DEV using `launchSettings.json`. But on the server machine, I should set the environment to PROD and then it automatically use the `appsettings.Production.json` file (respective json file). Is that all true?

Comment: @Maria yes, on the local machine you can switch environments using this file.

Comment: @GuruStron What about the other question related to the server machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all as docs state: `launchSettings.json` is [only used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) on the local development machine.

As for using configuration file - [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#default-configuration) next files are used:

> - `appsettings.json` using the JSON configuration provider.
> - `appsettings.Environment.json` using the JSON configuration provider. For example, `appsettings.Production.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`.

The environment for ASP.NET Core app determined [next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environments) way:

> To determine the runtime environment, ASP.NET Core reads from the following environment variables:
>
> - `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`
> - `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` when `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` is called. The default ASP.NET Core web app templates call `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`. The `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value overrides `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`.

So the usual approach is to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable to needed value on target host (machine, docker container, etc...)

Comment: **1.** I think I can set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` via cmd `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production`, etc. Is that true?

Comment: **2.** I have read using `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is better than `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` as it also supports Console apps. I am confused, which one should I prefer and why?

Comment: @Maria as written in the answer `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` if present overrides `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`, so I use the former one in my projects. As for setting environment variable on windows see [this](https://superuser.com/a/79614) answer.

Comment: @Maria also it seems that it can be set in [IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836533/2501279)

Comment: Thanks a lot again for all your useful helps. I think I should use `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` but not fully understand the difference exactly with `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` :)

Comment: Just a comment on the comments left by @Maria and the OP -  it is my understanding that the DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT is overridden by ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT as Maria stated, but if you have an .NET Core application that is not an ASP.NET Core application (e.g., a .NET Console application) you would need the DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT value to be explicitly set or the application will look instead for a commandline argument (if present), an appsettings.production.json file (if present), or it would just use the appsettings.json file by default.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0