# Automatically for dev and release in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have looked at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60961168/16814119) and have done what is described etc. But it's like that when I run my "API (dev)" it throws the contents into the database which is live. But in principle it should not do that. It should throw it into database_test but it does not.

Thus, when I run over in "API (prod)", it fails and I can thus not be allowed to throw things into the database.

appsettings.Development.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Db": "xxxx"<--- Test database
  }
```

appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "Db": "xxxx"<--- Live database
      }
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  xxxx,
  "profiles": {
    xxxxx,
    "API (prod)": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:8082;http://localhost:8444",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true"
    },
    "API (dev)": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:8081;http://localhost:8443",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true"
    },
    xxxxx
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
```

The problem is just that it throws it into the live database when I run dev, but then it throws the contents of the live database but I only want it to throw it into the test database. And when it's live, it's going to throw it in the live database.

EIDT - UPDATE.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("xxxxx");
        }
    }
```

have found that this is why I can not use test. So now I just have to figure out how I can get it done so that it makes use of testing when I dev and live when it's up.

Comment: For the prod part, you've hard-coded the Development to overwrite the base so I can't see how you'd ever be able to use the prod connection string.

Comment: Okay, so there's no way you can do that. I use Visual studio 2022. @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: It's just so if there is another way so I can make use of prod for live server and then the other for dev test database. @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: You should be able to do what you're trying to do but typically (from my xp anyway) you'd either have the env var or other param passed in to determine which secondary file you're trying to load. For example. `$"appsettings.{env}.json". Or tokenize a Release file and let the release pipeline inject the values according to the environment.

Comment: Try swapping out the following line with your second `AddJsonFile` call. `.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", true, true)`

Comment: okay, I try and then I'm still using it as I type in the launchSettings.json file. I've tried that now. And as I said, there is nothing to write between the two databases. @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: It would help if I actually followed your link to the guide ;). Added an answer after confirming that you can let the builder do the work and as long as your vars are set and available, you should have no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the guide you link to, you shouldn't need any explicit loading of the app settings files. It will, by default, load the `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.<Environment>.json` automatically. It will also automatically load any environment variables with an `ASPNETCORE_` prefix it finds. (or `DOTNET_` for generic hosts)

I would remove the redundant code. let the builder do its job, and ensure the environment variables are set and available when your app starts. If you can't find or get any value or the value you expect with `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")` then something's wrong with how they're being set.

Also, `appsettings.json` will load regardless of any issues with missing vars if it's present so I wouldn't put the production connection string there. Rather, put your local or dev connection string there and let the production value overwrite the dev/default value so you don't accidentally default to production.

Comment: I have make a eidt / update for my problem.

Comment: So is it that you were just ignoring your configs and hard-coding the connection string in `OnConfiguring`?

Comment: Yea i will try to remove this and move this to appsettings now.

Comment: I feel like this question is blown because now you have a completely different problem. All you need to do now is grab the connection string from the appsettings and set it on the `DbContext`.

Comment: Yea i will make this and thanks for help!