# How to get Azure Environment name

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Quick question. How can I get the name of the azure environment name (Production/Staging/QA) at run time in .net core? I tried
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") and System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT"). The first ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT only returns the environment when it runs locally.

Comment: Why do you need it? What are you trying to do differently when on prod/staging/QA environment?

Comment: WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME environment variable will indicate the deployment `slot`, it may help you.  Depends on how you manage your dev/QA environments.

Answer (score 1):

- Use the below line of code to get the Environment name in Azure

```cs
  var slot = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

- Add the Application settings in Configuration section of your Web App.

[image]

Please refer [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c) for more information