# Integrating Entity Framework Core into Class Library (.NET Standard)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core web app and a class library project in a single solution. My intention is to use the .NET Core web app just to serve as a web application and not use as a data layer. I have created the separate class library project for the sole purpose of creating the entity classes interact with the database. And I have included the entity framework core libraries into the class library project.

1. How can I include multiple configuration files (based on the environment, like `appsettings.development.json`, `appsettings.production.json` etc.) and read those values based on the environment I set?
2. How can I register the `DbContext` class in the class library, like in a ASP.NET Core web app below ?

This is a snippet of my ASP.NET Core web app `Startup` class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connString = Configuration.GetConntectionString("ConnectionStringKey");

    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connString));

    // other service configuration
}
```

Your input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Add these packages in your Class Library.**

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
```

**Create a static class to register DbContext**

```
public static  class ISserviceCollectionExtension
    {
        public static IServiceCollection configureservice(this IServiceCollection service, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            //access the appsetting json file in your WebApplication File

            string filePath = @"C:\your Web App path\appsettings.json";

            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath))
               .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json")
               .Build();

            service.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("xxx")));
            return service;
        }
    }
```

**DateContext**

```
 public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
    
        public DbSet<xx> xx{ get; set; }
        //.......
    }
```

**When you add migration, You may get the error like this:**

[image]

**Now you need create DbContextFactory class**

```
public class AppDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
    {
        public AppDbContextFactory()
        {

        }

        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
        public AppDbContextFactory(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {

            string filePath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\CheckPoint\NullMVC\appsettings.json";

            IConfiguration Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath))
               .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json")
               .Build();


            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("xxx"));

            return new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

**Finally, You can register and Migration DBContext in Class Library successfully.**

**The first question, You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c).**