# How to deploy ASP.NET Core Web API app with multiple appsettings.{env}.json files, to Service Fabric cluster

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have an existing ASP.NET Core Web API app (targeting .NET Core 2.0) which I want to deploy to a Service Fabric cluster. The app contains multiple environment-specific `appsettings.{env}.json` files. How can I deploy this to Service Fabric so that it picks DEV data from `appsettings.Development.json` file and PROD data from `appsettings.Production.json`.

At the moment, I use `launchSettings.json` file to set them during my development.

There is [an existing StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c) which is very similar but that is specific to the non-ServiceFabric way of deployment which assumes we have access to the deployed application or IIS. My question is specific to Service Fabric deployment.

Comment: Do you have a way of setting environment variables when running your application?

Comment: You'll need a way to set the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Development | Production | etc.` I'm not familiar with Service Fabric Cluster but this is the direction you should go to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically set appsettings.json for dev and release environments in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c)

Comment: @gunr2171 No. I just updated my question with the reason.

Comment: Isn't this what you're looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-how-to-specify-environment-variables?

Comment: Please refer [multiple configuration sources](https://dzimchuk.net/configuring-asp-net-core-applications-in-service-fabric/)