# switch between test and live settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a few setting like the database-connection that differ between my test- and live-system.
Has Visual Studio a feature that determines automatically which settings to use by just pulling one switch somewhere?
I don't want to use #if DEBUG because i still want to be able to debug my live-system before i publish it.
Is there no better way then just to use a bool?

Comment: What about using a configuration file that you can swap?

Comment: What does "better" mean? You can't get much simpler that a single bit...

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c).

Comment: First of all: What type of Project are we talking about and what dotnet Version is in use? Answers may vary vastly depending on whether this is cloud-related, a desktop app in WinForms ...

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods it's a blazor server app + class libraries in ASP.NET core 6.0

Comment: @HereticMonkey my question was just if there's a build in feature of VS that makes switching between variables before build easy. that would be the recommended way, no? if not, i'm just gonna use a const bool

Answer (score -1):

The best way to make changes based on environment is using environment variables
For example you can put a variable name “environmentName” and put its value as develop,prod,stage or any other

Then you can pull it and preform different actions based on it

String env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("environmentName");

Answer (score -1):

Id recommend environment variables from personal experience.

See here for a simple explanation: https://mahmudx.com/how-to-store-and-retrieve-environment-variable-in-csharp