# Start multiple projects in VS as specific environment

Tags: visual-studio, environment-variables

Let's say I have 3 projects in a Visual Studio 2022 solution; `Web`, `Shared`, `Repo`. Web is dependent to the other two (all three need to run for Web to work).
I also have 3 environments; `DEV`, `ACC`, `PRD`. These environments have different settings; (connectionstrings, paths, baseurls etc) and they all have their own appsettings-files in all three projects (appsettings+dev+acc+prd → correct ones imported at startup)

Everything works... I've setup different profiles in all three `launchSettings.json` with their own environmentVariables for every project so that I can simply just start a project as an ACC-profile or PRD-profile by using the PLAY button in Visual Studio. However I need to manually change every child project to the correct profile before actually running the main Web-project.

Is it possible to make this easier? I guess what would work PERFECT is if I could have all child related project using the environment variables from the main running project:

[image]

I have actually not tried just to remove the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable from all child projects.... :-D but not sure that is what I want either for sometimes that child-project might be the main starting project in another case.

And just to be clear, in my case there are of course many many project and not just three.

Comment: Did actually find a kind of work-around
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364293/automatically-set-appsettings-json-for-dev-and-release-environments-in-asp-net-c
It's kind of weird you need to do this manually I think .. but that might be what I need to do as well.

Comment: Would be nice if there was a VS plugin or something that put a big drop-down in the toolbar where you choose the environment and it will update all launchsettings at build

Comment: I actually found this ext. in VS (SolutionEnvironment) and it works kind of good. What you need to do though is to remove all the env.variables from the profiles (they will override) and also do a rebuild whenever you change the environment. That rebuild is kind of a pain and will be forgotten many times. I've also been thinking of the "global"-file solution and read the environment from it first but I don't think that works for me, coz when I publish to servers the file will be incl and set the environment accordingly, then I need to remove the file or hardcode a machinename or whatever...